# Fetch the browser defined text from a file input (e.g. "Choose file")

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am working on a multilingual jQuery wrapper for input[type="file"].
There are lots of other wrappers of that kind, but most of them have hard-coded values that replace browser-predefined text (e.g. "Choose file",  "No file chosen").

Is it possible to get the predefined text from the file input and use those values in my wrapper, without hard-coding them?

Comment: tidied up, more descriptive title

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for localization, you could use JQuery plugin for the same.

https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties